# WHERE statement does not work in unit test using It.IsAny

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, unit-testing, mocking

I have some problem with unit test of my repository, especially with method `FindBy()`

```
public IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
   return Entities.Where(predicate);
}
```

Entities is `IDbSet<T> Entities = _context.Set<T>();`

I'm trying to test the method in controller, but I always get `NULL` in `houses`. 
Could you give any advice what should I do with it?

```
public override HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var houses = Repository.FindBy(y => y.Year == DateTime.Now.Year);

    if (houses != null && houses.Any())
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, houses);
    }

    const string message = "House: No content";
    return ErrorMsg(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
}
```

Here is my test method

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetAll()
{   //Arrange
    var houses = new List<House>
     {
         new House {ID = 1, BuildNr = "01", HouseNr = "001" },
         new House {ID = 2, BuildNr = "02", HouseNr = "002" },
         new House {ID = 3, BuildNr = "03", HouseNr = "003" },
         new House {ID = 4, BuildNr = "04", HouseNr = "004" },
         new House {ID = 5, BuildNr = "05", HouseNr = "005" }
     };

    var mock = new Mock<IRepository<T>>();
    mock.Setup(m => m.FindBy(f => f.Year == It.IsAny<int>()))
        .Returns(houses.AsQueryable());
    //...

    var controller = new HouseController(mock.Object);
    //Action
    var response = controller.Get();
    var result = response.ContentToQueryable<T>();
    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(5, result.Count());
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact syntax, but you can access parameters passed into the call from `.Returns`. So you could write (pseudocode); `.Setup(It.IsAny<Thing>()).Returns((predicate) => houses.Where(predicate).AsQueryable());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not the correct way to use It.IsAny, which is intended to substitute a whole parameter, and not be part of one - in this case, you would use it (something) like this for an unspecified predicate:

```
 mock.Setup(m => m.FindBy(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<int, bool>>>())
```

As you already know that the controller method will use the current year, use that for the setup:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.FindBy(f => f.Year == DateTime.Now.Year))
```

Then, if the controller method is accidentally changed to use the wrong value, your test will fail.

Comment: Be aware the second example can break once a year.. :)

Comment: @Rob one of my colleagues tried to mitigate the issue of dates in unit tests by using a "TimeProvider" class. Unfortunately he made it a static class, so once tests started to be run concurrently, they would stomp over each others' expected time values. Fun times :)